# get param from url in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Now I'm doing 'dirty' split to get any id from the url. I'm not sure how to utilise react router, I did something like this

```
this.__isEdit = (this.props.history.location.pathname.indexOf('edit') > -1)

const pathnameArr = this.props.history.location.pathname.split('/')
this.__todoId = pathnameArr[pathnameArr.length - 2] //get second last arr
```

for one of my route

```
<Route exact path='/admin/ad/:id/edit' component={createTodoComponent} />
```

Anyway I can improve it the code?

Comment: are you using Redux?

Comment: which version of React-router do you use

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri v4.

Comment: @DaleFrancis yes but this has nothing to do with redux I guess?

Answer (score 6):

So for you component you'll need to wrap it with the withRouter method from 'react-router-dom' then you can get any of the params from this.props

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const component = ({match}) => {
    const id = match.params.id

    return (
        <span>{id}</span>
    )
}

export default withRouter(component)
```

or if you want to do it with the React component class

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class NewComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const {match} = this.props
        const id = match.params.id

        return (
            <span>{id}</span>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(NewComponent)
```

Comment: this is pure component what if my component is a class?

Comment: Its the same thing. you just pass the component class into withRouter and then do this.props.match.params.id

Answer (score 0):

react router params are available on this.props.params inside the connected component.

Comment: nope. Not in react router v4